# SSRS: Any UpperCase function in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to display selected month, current month and last month names on my report.  I am using

```
=Parameters!Month.Label ---> Jun 2016(selected)
```

`=Format(Now(), "MMM") & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy") ---> Dec 2016 (current)`
`=Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now()), "MMM") & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy")  ---> Nov 2016 (last)`

But I need something like(JUNE 2016, DECEMBER 2016, NOVEMBER 2016 ). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[UCase Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53e2ew8a(v=vs.90).aspx)

`=UCase(Format(Now(), "MMM") & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy"))`

`=UCase(Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now()), "MMM") & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy"))`

Comment: Thank you so much for replying but I have already tried this one and getting an error  "Name Upper is not declared"

Comment: Then you're using it wrong - show us your exact expression text and we can tell you how. If you've tried something which you thought should have worked but didn't, you should give details in your question - it will help people give you better answers and resolve your question faster.

Comment: Before posting the question i tried   '=Upper(Format(Now(), "MMM") & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy"))' and '=(Format(Upper(Now(), "MMM")) & " " & Format(Now(), "yyyy"))' but its not working and throwing an error.

Comment: My apologies, the function you need in SSRS is from VB: `UCase` - I accidentally found the SSIS (not SSRS) syntax by mistake! I have edited my answer accordingly for you and confirmed it works for me in Report Builder.

Comment: Ohh thank you sooo much. so saved me. it is working  now. bless you dear

Comment: No problem - please consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful, sorry for the initial confusion!